# How to stabilize the output square wave of a TL074CN (Comparator)

Tags: operational-amplifier, power-electronics, oscilloscope, comparator, passive-networks

**Figure 1**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsQ4Cr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I am using a TL074CN comparator to compare a fullwave rectified input voltage with a DC voltage of 1.4 V as shown in the above figure. At the output of the comparator, I am receiving a square wave which goes from +12V to -12V.

---

**Figure 2**

[image]

The figure 2 above shows the square wave generated in microsecond level. As you can see the waveform is very unstable at the moment. So far what I tried was

1) I also added a 100u capacitor at the output of the opmamp but it doesn't stabilize the waveform , it instead curves the waveform at the edges

2) I added a 10K resistor at the output but it doesn't help either.

3) I switched the TL074CN with an LM324N and still did not stabilize the waveform

Is there anything which I can do to make this square wave stable?

Comment: What makes you certain that the jitter you're seeing isn't actually in your input source?

Comment: What are you using to trigger your oscilloscope?

Comment: @duskwuff
I have channel 1, 2 and 3.

Channel 1 is the DC source of +12 and -12 with a potentiometer.
Channel 2 is the Fullwave rectifier waveform.
Channel 3 is the square wave

I was using channel 2 which is the full wave rectifier waveform and it displayed an unstable square wave. But when I changed to channel 3, the results were different which I have explained in a separate answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The TL074 and LM324 are op-amps, not comparators.

If you want a device to operate as a comparator, you should use something designed for that application, like an LM319.

Comment: Op amps generally work fine as comparators, as long as they have plenty of bandwidth.

Comment: @ConnorWolf

So that means if an OPAMP doesn't have much bandwidth, it cannot be used as a comparator? What is the reason for this?

Comment: @Amy It's generally [not a good idea to use an op amp as a comparator](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/194324/51760). You'll get better performance from a comparator than an op amp in a comparator circuit. Unless you only have op amps on hand or you have a spare op amp (e.g. you're only using three op amps in a quad op amp IC) there's little reason to use an op amp instead of a comparator.

Answer (score 0):

**Figure 3**

[image]

My error was that I was not triggering correctly. This time I selected the trigger mode to channel 3 which is the output square wave and selected the "slope" to be falling.

As you can see that when slope was selected to be falling, the **falling edge** of the square wave is stable while the **rising edge** shows some instability.

And when experimented vice versa, the rising edge was stable while the falling edge was not.