# Compare same signal with different voltage thresholds using op amps

Tags: operational-amplifier, transistors

I would like to use two op amps to drive a transistor when receiving two different voltage ranges from the same input signal for a project. For example, I would like to switch the transistor on when the input signal is below 2V or above 4V.

I wonder what is the best approach to solve this.

I am new to this, so please be patient.

Comment: I'd like to suggest a search on "window comparator" so you could familiarize yourself with this approach and edit the question to make it less broad.

Comment: Comparators are a bit like op-amps but don't suffer latch-up problems when the inputs are driven close to supply rails. Their open-collector or open-drain outputs make it easy to create an OR function on the two comparators of a window comparator. Plent of examples on the web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are describing a [window comparator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_detector) application, which typically uses comparators instead of op amps. See [one of my other answers to understand the difference between a comparator and op amp, and why to avoid using an op amp when a comparator is needed](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/194324/51760).

Since you need two comparators, a dual comparator IC chip will work well in this application. Some such ICs' datasheets will even show a window comparator application for you. For example, [page 22 of the LM393LV dual comparator datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm393lv.pdf?ts=1659195778189&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FLM393LV) shows a window comparator design. You haven't specified a supply voltage or which transistor you are driving so you'll have to adapt the datasheet's design hints to your needs.